# Выборка min() c группировкой по двум значениям

Tags: sql, postgresql

Необходимо сделать выборку по таблице, содержащей поля user_id(идентификатор объекта события) и logdate (дата и время события). Результирующая таблица должна содержать user_id, столбец даты события (без времени), и столбец минимального времени события за эту дату.

```
  SELECT Cast(datein AS DATE)
        ,min(datein) mineventT
    FROM "TEST" where user_id = 20467
    GROUP BY Cast(datein AS DATE)
```

Эта выборка возвращает и группирует по дате для отдельного объекта, но как сгруппировать данные таким образом, чтобы получить минимальное время для каждого объекта за каждый день, где оно существует?

Comment: *как сгруппировать данные таким образом, чтобы получить минимальное время для каждого объекта за каждый день, где оно существует?* Очевидно, что группировать надо не только по дню, но ещё и по юзеру. `GROUP BY user_id, CAST(datein AS DATE)`

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте воспользоваться оконными функциями, rank к примеру. Скрипт будет примерно такой:
Select user_id, cast(datein as date), datein, rank() over(partition by user_id, cast(datein as date) order by datein asc) as my_rank
from test
Where my_rank = 1;